# Why does EUnit compile .beam files into .eunit/ebin?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, eunit, erlang-ports

*Disclaimer: The author of this question has mostly theoretical knowledge of Erlang/OTP.*

I have a small OTP application which calls some non-Erlang executable inside the `myapp/ebin` directory via `open_port()`. When I run the application itself everything goes well and the port to the executable is successfully opened.

But when I try to run unit tests for the application, the ones that depend on the `open_port()` fail, because when started with `EUnit` the application tries to find the executable under `myapp/.eunit/ebin`.

How can I change that behaviour without changing the code of the application itself? How can I run EUnit tests with the same current directory as when running the application itself? (I mean it would not be a good idea to change the code which provides the path to the executable just to be able to run EUnit).

Edit: I followed the advice in the Erlang [mailing list](http://lists.basho.com/pipermail/rebar_lists.basho.com/2011-January/000473.html), but `code:priv_dir(myapp_name)` returns `{error, bad_name}`.

Edit: I can see that `.eunit/` contains `modulename.beam` files and `ebin/` contains both `modulename.beam` files and `modulename_tests.beam` files. Now I am completely lost.  When I run `make test`, `rebar` runs `eunit` command, which calls each `modulename_tests.beam` file in the `ebin/` directory which calls a corresponding `modulename.beam` file in the `.eunit/` directory (`filename:absname("")` clearly shows that `modulename.beam` files are executed from `.eunit/` during test). Why is it so? Why do we need to run `modulename.beam` files from the `.eunit/` directory instead of `ebin/`?

Why do we actually need to have the very same .beam files in `myapp/ebin` and `myapp/.eunit/ebin`?

P.S. I have read the [official documentation](http://ww.erlang.org/doc/apps/eunit/chapter.html#Unit_testing) and did not find the solution.

Answer (score 5):

EUnit does not do this by itself - the .eunit directory is a convention used by Rebar.

Comment: Can I somehow make rebar to compile into ebin/ instead of .eunit/? And will it break something in the app build?

Comment: You could fork and patch rebar https://github.com/basho/rebar/blob/master/src/rebar_eunit.erl#L74

Answer (score 1):

To use `erlang` start script ".erlang" , and it can solve your problem.

In the .erlang file, to use `code:add_pathz/N` to add your necessary path.

Before reading `couchdb` source code there is example of how to use `priv` directory. Maybe the solution is helpful to you. It wrap `open_port` with `start_port` function, and set the directory in `start_port` function.

In file `couch_os_daemon.erl`

```
start_port(Command) ->
    PrivDir = couch_util:priv_dir(),
    Spawnkiller = filename:join(PrivDir, "couchspawnkillable"),
    Port = open_port({spawn, Spawnkiller ++ " " ++ Command}, ?PORT_OPTIONS),
    {ok, Port}.


stop_port(#daemon{port=Port, kill=undefined}=D) ->
    ?LOG_ERROR("Stopping daemon without a kill command: ~p", [D#daemon.name]),
    catch port_close(Port);
stop_port(#daemon{port=Port}=D) ->
    ?LOG_DEBUG("Stopping daemon: ~p", [D#daemon.name]),
    os:cmd(D#daemon.kill),
    catch port_close(Port).
```

In file couch_util.erl

```
priv_dir() ->
    case code:priv_dir(couch) of
        {error, bad_name} ->
            % small hack, in dev mode "app" is couchdb. Fixing requires
            % renaming src/couch to src/couch. Not really worth the hassle.
            % -Damien
            code:priv_dir(couchdb);
        Dir -> Dir
    end.

start_driver(LibDir) ->
    case erl_ddll:load_driver(LibDir, "couch_icu_driver") of
    ok ->
        ok;
    {error, already_loaded} ->
        ok = erl_ddll:reload_driver(LibDir, "couch_icu_driver");
    {error, Error} ->
        exit(erl_ddll:format_error(Error))
    end.
```

You can grep `priv`, many example can be found.

Comment: Dear Chen, is there any way to add this path dynamically? Adding a hardcoded value with code:add_pathsz() will not help when working with the code on another machine.

Comment: How about code:priv_dir(Application) function? It will return your application's priv path, and you can store the object file in the priv's subdirectory, it is used for other machine for returning the other machine's path.